# Problem with data sharedpreferences - Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, sharedpreferences

When I take the data from SharedPreferences, it does not show it in the string and gives an error in this line accountName: `Text(sharedPreferenceEmail)`,
in error shows that sharedPreferenceEmail = null

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  String sharedPreferenceEmail;
  String value;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDataPreference();
  }

  getDataPreference() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      value = sharedPreferences.getString("email");
      if(value != null) {
        sharedPreferenceEmail = sharedPreferences.getString("email");
      } else {
        sharedPreferenceEmail = "Sign in with Google";
      }
    });
  }

UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueGrey[900]),
                accountName: Text(
                  sharedPreferenceEmail
                  ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfUZG.png)

Comment: What happens if you use `accountName: sharedPreferenceEmail != null ?  Text(
                  sharedPreferenceEmail
                  ) : Container(),`?

Comment: and what to put in Container() ?

Comment: Nothing, it's just a placeholder until the data from shared preferences becomes available. It's async and arrives with some delay, until then display an empty `Container()`.

Comment: I can not write it in ```accountName```  it is underlined

Comment: Sorry, don't know what that means.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, everything helped, thank you so much!)))

Answer (score 3):

If you acquire a value using async execution, you need to guard agains `null` to not cause an exception when Flutter builds while the result hasn't arrived yet:

```
accountName: sharedPreferenceEmail != null ? Text( sharedPreferenceEmail ) : Container(),
```

Comment: Thanks for the help)

Comment: If it solves your problem don't forget to accept the answer clicking the checkmark on the left below the up/down-vote button.